# Greetings - about cookies?

Tags: cookies

I'm not a web developer but I seem to have taken over our business website.

It uses 
apnexus
doubleclick and
google analytics

I need to make sure we are prepared for the GDPR and seek consent from any new visitor.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Are these built into all Craft CMS sites?  Will they be updated to follow the new regulations?

thank you ...

Comment: There is nothing built into Craft out of the box to handle this.  How familiar are you with JavaScript or any coding in particular?  And to be clear, you're wanting a cookie policy message to appear to first-time users and then go away when they click "I accept"?

Comment: Thanks for you answer Ryan.  I use the dashboard basically to update web elements.  I do know coding but I can't get at the coding behind our website.  I suspect that is in the purview of our providers.  And yes, I want to be able to either remove those cookies or get consent from first time browsers.  The GDPR requires positive agreement for cookies. ..

Comment: There may be a way to ftp the site, but we have not been informed of it.  I will seek that information from our providers ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ryan has said in the comments, there currently isn't a native cookie consent feature within Craft CMS.

You'll need to either install a plugin ([Cookie Consent plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/xkisu/craftcookieconsent) is good) or use a service like [Silk Tide Cookie Consent](https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/download/).

Both options require you to have access to your website via FTP.

For the plugin, you'll upload it to the /craft/plugins/ directory and activate it via the Craft CMS control panel.

The [Silk Tide](https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/download/) method requires you to add some code between the `<head></head>` tags.

If you need help with this, there are lots of developers on here (including myself) that can help.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you've pointed me in the right direction.  I need to get FTP access!

Comment: Awesome :) If you're happy with my answer, please accept it by pressing the tick.